# iframe width on screen and mobile device

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe.

I'm trying to make it be full screen width on a mobile device and be half the screen on a normal monitor (100% and 50%).  The mobile device minimum spec would be iPhone, but if it works on Android then that would be a big plus.

I can use HTML and CSS.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try media queries to conditionally include a css:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" 
    href="mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: This worked for making the iphone show the right width, but where do I put the default width (100%) element so it doesn't get overwritten?